# Why I can't use (if (last acc) acc) inside a loop being acc one of the arguments?

Tags: recursion, clojure, functional-programming

```
(defn build-vector [n]
  (loop [acc []
          n 0]
    (if (>= (last acc) n)
      acc
      (recur (conj acc n) (inc n)))))


(defn build-vector-2 [n]
    (loop [acc []
           m 0]
          (if (>= m n)
            acc
            (recur (conj acc m) (inc m)))))
```

Both functions are exactly the same, the only difference the usage of `(last acc)` inside the `if` block. Why the first one fails while the second one works?

Running here:

```
(defn -main
  []
  (println (build-vector 9)))
```

I got this error stack:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException, compiling:(/tmp/form-init7896039701880984157.clj:1:73)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7391)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7317)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invokeStatic(main.clj:275)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:277)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:277)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invokeStatic(main.clj:308)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:342)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:339)
    at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:421)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:384)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at clojure.lang.Numbers.ops(Numbers.java:1013)
    at clojure.lang.Numbers.gte(Numbers.java:233)
    at clojure.lang.Numbers.gte(Numbers.java:3888)
    at test_aj07mm.core$build_vector.invokeStatic(core.clj:14)
    at test_aj07mm.core$build_vector.invoke(core.clj:11)
    at test_aj07mm.core$_main.invokeStatic(core.clj:39)
    at test_aj07mm.core$_main.invoke(core.clj:37)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:375)
    at user$eval5.invokeStatic(form-init7896039701880984157.clj:1)
    at user$eval5.invoke(form-init7896039701880984157.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6927)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6917)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7379)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: This is besides the question, but I'll just point it out in case your code here isn't just toy code: to create a vector of numbers of increasing value, you can just write `(vec (range n))`, where `n` is the max number (exclusive), and the size of the vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the first iteration `acc` is the empty vector, so `(last acc)` returns nil. `(>= nil 0)` throws a `NullPointerException`.